# Picking particular date from calender using selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, date

I want to pick particular date (01-Jun-1990) from calendar: can you please help me in this case? PFA snap shot.

[image]

Thanks, 
Dileep

Answer (score 0):

Print the *value* attribute
e.g.

```
<input id="meeting" type="date" />
```

`getElementById('meeting').value` will print the required value.